# Having trouble reading a value from View.ascx.resx from code behind

Tags: asp.net, localization

I have the following files: View.ascx, View.ascx.cs, View.ascx.resx .  In the file View.ascx.resx, I'm have a lot of trouble reading the value for the key `EmailAddress.Text` from my code behind.

I tried this:

```
  object keyValue = System.Web.HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject("~/View.aspx", "EmailAddress", culture);
  EmailAddress.Attributes["placeholder"] = keyValue.ToString();
```

And it gave me the error:

```
Error: Contact is currently unavailable. DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException: The resource class for this page was not found. Please check if the resource file exists and try again. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The resource class for this page was not found. Please check if the resource file exists and try again. at System.Web.Compilation.LocalResXResourceProvider.CreateResourceManager() at System.Web.Compilation.BaseResXResourceProvider.EnsureResourceManager() at System.Web.Compilation.BaseResXResourceProvider.GetObject(String resourceKey, CultureInfo culture) at System.Web.Compilation.ResourceExpressionBuilder.GetResourceObject(IResourceProvider resourceProvider, String resourceKey, CultureInfo culture, Type objType, String propName) at System.Web.HttpContext.GetLocalResourceObject(String virtualPath, String resourceKey, CultureInfo culture) at com.John.Contact.View.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\john\Documents\My Web Sites\v624\DesktopModules\Contact\View.ascx.cs:line 74 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I tried this:

```
            ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("items", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            String r = rm.GetString("EmailAddress");
```

And it gave me this error:

```
Error: Contact is currently unavailable. DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture. Make sure "items.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "Contact" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed. ---> System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture. Make sure "items.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "Contact" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed. at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.HandleResourceStreamMissing(String fileName) at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Dictionary`2 localResourceSets, Boolean tryParents, Boolean createIfNotExists, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo requestedCulture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents) at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo culture) at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name) at com.John.Contact.View.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\john\Documents\My Web Sites\v624\DesktopModules\Contact\View.ascx.cs:line 80 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I tried several other example from the asp.net code library, but kept getting other errors.  How do I grab a value from the View.ascx.resx file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally figured it out.  I have to use the DotNetNuke API because this is a DotNetNuke project.

```
String s = DotNetNuke.Services.Localization.Localization.GetString("EmailAddress",this.LocalResourceFile);
```